Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined in Payload CMS
my webpack config
error image here
Hello community! Recently, I’ve been working on a project using Payload CMS, a powerful headless CMS. Unfortunately, I’ve encountered some issues related to SDKs where Payload doesn’t effectively separate server-side code from client-side code. Additionally, certain libraries that exist only in the Node environment end up being loaded on the client side. These libraries are part of the SDK. In my specific case, I’m working with Socket.IO, and I’ve been encountering an error when trying to access the Payload CMS admin.
Has anyone found a solution to address these issues? The documentation doesn’t provide much guidance, and the limited information available hasn’t worked for me so far. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I already tried with the solutions that payload gives me to create aliases in the webpack configuration but that has not worked for me
